# mathematical logic with arguments determinate

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I don't know how to handle the part with name.I think it is someone like a set.

Can anybody help me with question a only. Once I understand question a ,I think I can tackle rest of it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe propositional logic is not enough and you need predicate logic ("All students...").

Comment: I want to know how to state "Xavier is a student in class".

Comment: Student-in-class(Xavier)

Comment: $\forall x (StuInCl(x) \to UndLog(x))$ and $StuInCl(X)$. Therefore...